# directed graph with minimum number of chains

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I have a problem but I can't figure out a solution. It goes like this:

I have a directed graph with *N* nodes and *M* links and without cycles. I need to find out the minimum numbers of chains so every node belongs to only one chain.

Example:

> 7 11 7 nodes; 11 links
>   1 2
>   1 5
>   2 3
>   2 5
>   2 7
>   3 4 // link exists between 3 and 4
>   3 6
>   4 6
>   5 4
>   5 6
>   7 3

Answer is: 2

An example is
Chain: 2-7-3-6
Chain: 1-5-4

Thanks.

Comment: "without cycles"... "i need to find out the minimum numbers of cycles"? You mean chains, right?

Comment: yeah sorry i will modify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He doesn't need to know if the graph is hamiltonian - knowing that it's a DAG is enough. It's probably a contest or online judge problem? It does look too hard to be homework.

Solution here: http://www2.cs.science.cmu.ac.th/person/rogaway/ps3-solns.pdf

To find the matching efficiently, consider the Hopcroft Karp algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm

Comment: it seems that these is the answer.